# Turning a list into a nested list where the next value is 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I turn a list such as:

```
data_list = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,1,2,3,3]
```

into a list of lists such as:

```
new_list = [ [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,3], [1,2,3,3] ]
```

Comment: It would help to try something and show us that attempt. We aren't just here to write code for you. How do you think you could approach the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Using a loop:

```
data = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,1,2,3,3]
result =[]

for n in data:
    if n == 1 or result == []:
        result.append([])
    result[-1].append(n)
```

---

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a generator like this?

```
def grouped(it, boundary):
    group = []
    for val in it:
        if val == boundary and group:
            yield group
            group = []
        group.append(val)
    if group:
        yield group

for grp in grouped([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3,1,2,3,3], 1):
    print(grp)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 3]
```